# Get Wordpress feed in Foundation 6

Tags: wordpress, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I would like to get my Wordpress blog posts to feed into my Foundation 6 site automatically. So I have a blog on Wordpress and would like everytime I write a post for it to show up in my site that is hosted somewhere else. Like a Twitter feed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand what you desire. There are many "rss feed parser" OR "rss php scripts" OR "rss feed display widget" on the net. Shouldn't take more than 3 hours to learn the entire process.

- https://feed2js.org/index.php?s=build
- https://www.rssinclude.com/
- http://codecanyon.net/item/rss-feed-generator/304388
- http://simplepie.org/
- http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-create-an-rss-feed-for-your-site-from-scratch/

I remember years ago, there was a GNARLY dude who had a website that pumped out the `<script>` code and all you had to do was insert your blog URL. The site had a GUI with customization options like colors, font size, etc...it was pretty mean too because this was back in 2011. I just couldn't find it for you but if I do, I'll report back here and drop the link.